# How to adjust transparency (alpha) in seaborn swarmplot?

Tags: seaborn, alpha, swarmplot

I have a swarmplot:

```
sns.swarmplot(y = "age gap corr", x = "cluster", 
              data = scatter_data, hue = 'group', dodge=True)
```

and I would like to adjust the transparency of the dots:

```
sns.swarmplot(y = "age gap corr", x = "cluster", 
              data = scatter_data, hue = 'group', dodge=True,
              scatter_kws = {'alpha': 0.1})

sns.swarmplot(y = "age gap corr", x = "cluster", 
              data = scatter_data, hue = 'group', dodge=True,
              plot_kws={'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.1}})
```

but neither of the above methods works.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply input the `alpha` argument directly in the `swarmplot` function:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds').sample(1000)
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='cut', y='carat', hue='color', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

The documentation for `swarmplot` states

> kwargs : *key, value mappings*
>
> Other keyword arguments are passed through to matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter().

Thus, you don't need to use `scatter_kws={...}`.

Compare this to, e.g., `sns.lmplot`, which states

> {scatter,line}_kws : *dictionaries*
>
> Additional keyword arguments to pass to plt.scatter and plt.plot.